# SQL Validate a column with the same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following situation. I have a table with all info of article. I will like to compare the same column with it self. because I have multiple type of article. Single product and Master product. the only way that I have to differences it, is by SKU. for example.

```
ID |   SKU   
1   | 11111 
2   | 11112  
3   | 11113 
4   | 11113-5  
5   | 11113-8 
6   | 11114  
7   | 11115 
8   | 11115-1-W 
9   | 11115-2 
10  | 11116
```

I only want to list or / and count only the sku that are full unique. follow th example the sku that are unique and no have variant are (ID = 1, 2, 6 and 10) I will want to create a query where if 11113 are again on the column not cout it. so in total I will be 4 unique sku and not "6 (on total)".  Please let me know. if this are possible.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a table of what your desired output will look like.

Comment: Is the length of the "master" SKU always exactly 5 characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by grouping and counting the unique rows.

First, we will need to take your table and add a new column, `MasterSKU`.  This will be the first five characters of the `SKU` column.  Once we have the `MasterSKU`, we can then `GROUP BY` it. This will bundle together all of the rows having the same `MasterSKU`.  Once we are grouping we get access to aggregate functions like `COUNT()`.  We will use that function to count the number of rows for each `MasterSKU`.  Then, we will filter out any rows that have a `COUNT()` over 1. That will leave you with only the unique rows remaining.

Take that unique list and `LEFT JOIN` it back into your original table to grab the IDs.

```
SELECT ID, A.MasterSKU
FROM (
    SELECT
        MasterSKU = SUBSTRING(SKU,1,5),
        MasterSKUCount = COUNT(*)
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(SKU,1,5)
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
) AS A
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ID,
        MasterSKU = SUBSTRING(SKU,1,5)
    FROM MyTable
) AS B
ON A.MasterSKU = B.MasterSKU
```

[image]

Now one thing I noticed from you example.  The original SKU column really looks like three columns in one.  We have multiple values being joined with hypens.

`11115-1-W`

There may be a reason for it, but most likely this violates [first normal form](http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/first-normal-form-1nf.php) and will make the database hard to query. It's part of the reason why such a complicated query is needed. If the SKU column really represents multiple things then we may want to consider breaking it out into MasterSKU, Version, and Color or whatever each hyphen represents.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the length of master SKUs are 5 characters, try this:

```
select a.*
from mytable a
left join mytable b on b.sku like concat(a.sku, '%')
where length(a.sku) = 5
and b.sku is null
```

This query joins master SKUs to child ones, but filters out successful joins - leaving only solitary master SKUs.

Comment: Compared to my answer, filtering on length makes for a much cleaner query.  Nice.